# Inertia of a block matrix using another block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices

How can we calculate the inertia of the block matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}0&-A^*\\-A&I\end{bmatrix}$$? Here $A$ is an $n\times n$ complex matrix and $I$ is the identity matrix of order $n$.

Is using the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}0&I\\I&A\end{bmatrix}$$ helpful here. This last matrix is, I think of full rank, hence invertible. May be we could use the Sylvester's law of inertia here. Do we need to assume that $A$ and $A^T$ are invertible here? Any hints? thanks beforehand.

Comment: Do you mean $A^\ast$ instead of $A^T$?

Comment: @user1551 ok, edited, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A\in M_n(\mathbb C)$ has rank $r$ and $A=USV^\ast$ is a singular value decomposition. Then
$$
M:=\pmatrix{0&-A^\ast\\ -A&I}
\cong\pmatrix{0&S\\ S&I}
\cong\bigoplus_{i=1}^n\pmatrix{0&\sigma_i\\ \sigma_i&1}=:\bigoplus_{i=1}^nB_i.
$$
Since $B_i=\operatorname{diag}(0,1)$ when $\sigma_i=0$ and $B_i\cong\operatorname{diag}(-1,1)$ when $\sigma_i>0$, we conclude that $n_+=n,\,n_-=r$ and $n_0=n-r$. That is, $M\cong I_n\oplus-I_r\oplus0_{(n-r)\times(n-r)}$.

Comment: thanks! but cant we use the last matrix I had shown in the OP?

Comment: @vidyarthi I don't see its relevance. Would you please elaborate?

Comment: and I just cannot get how you jumped from the singular value decomposition to $B_i$. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @vidyarthi There isn't any jump. $B_i$ is defined to be $\pmatrix{0&\sigma_i\\ \sigma_i&1}$.

Comment: I mean is the inertia of $M$ equal to that of the last matrix I showed in the OP

Comment: @vidyarthi $\pmatrix{0&I\\ I&A}$ is always invertible, but $M$ is not (consider e.g. $A=0$). The two matrices therefore do not necessarily have the same inertia.

Comment: I found a way through the matrix I showed, see my answer below. By the way, your answer is also great and applies to general situations. Is the Haynsworth formula applicable here?

Answer (score 1):

We have $$\begin{bmatrix}0&I\\I&A^*\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0&-A^*\\-A&I\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0&I\\I&A\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}I&0\\0&-A^*A\end{bmatrix}$$.

Thus, by the Sylvester's law of inertia, the number of positive eigenvalues equal $n$, negative eigenvalues equal the rank of $A$ and zero eigenvlaues equal the nullity of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

You can almost eyeball the result with 2 applications of Cauchy Interlacing.
$M=\begin{bmatrix}0&-A^*\\-A&I_n\end{bmatrix}$

**0.)** Regarding geometric multiplicity of eigenvalue $0$
$\dim\ker\big(M\big) =\dim\ker\big(A\big)$
to see this
$\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf 0\\\mathbf 0\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}0&-A^*\\-A&I\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf x\\\mathbf y\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}-A^*\mathbf y\\ -A\mathbf x+\mathbf y\end{bmatrix} $
i) $A^*\mathbf y = \mathbf 0$
ii.) $A\mathbf x = \mathbf y$  but $0 =\mathbf y^*A\mathbf x = \mathbf y^*\mathbf y\implies \mathbf y = \mathbf 0$
Thus $A\mathbf x = 0$  with vectors of the form $\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf x\\\mathbf 0\end{bmatrix}$ characterize the kernel of $M$

Now let $\mathbf e_k$ denote the kth standard basis vector in $\mathbb C^{2n}$

**1.)**  $B_1 := \bigg[\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
\mathbf e_1 & \mathbf e_2 &\cdots  &\mathbf e_n
\end{array}\bigg]$
$B_1^*MB_1 = \mathbf 0$
tells us that $M$ has $n$ eigenvalues $\geq 0$ and $n$ eigenvalues $\leq 0$

**2.)** $B_2 = \bigg[\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
\mathbf e_{n+1} & \mathbf e_{n+2} &\cdots & \mathbf e_{2n}
\end{array}\bigg]$
$B_2^*MB_2 = I_n$
tells us that $M$ has $n$ eigenvalues $\geq 1$

thus  $M$ has signature $\Big(n,r\Big) = \Big(n,n - \dim\ker\big(A\big)\Big)$